# Mysql query the most visited url per user

Tags: mysql

I need to count the urls with the most visits per user.

Table name:visit_actions:  mysql version:5.7

```sql
+----+--------+---------+---------------------+
| id | url_id | user_id | server_time         |
+----+--------+---------+---------------------+
|  1 | 265338 |       4 | 2019-11-07 08:54:47 |
|  2 | 265405 |       1 | 2019-11-07 08:55:21 |
|  3 | 265391 |       4 | 2019-11-07 08:56:03 |
|  4 | 265338 |       1 | 2019-11-07 08:57:36 |
|  5 | 265338 |       1 | 2019-11-07 10:02:46 |
| 21 | 265207 |       5 | 2019-11-08 02:17:30 |
| 22 | 265207 |       5 | 2019-11-08 02:17:30 |
+----+--------+---------+---------------------+
```

I have tried this sql:

```sql
SELECT
 url_id,
 user_id,
 count( * ) AS visit_times 
FROM
 visit_actions 
GROUP BY
 user_id,
 url_id 
ORDER BY
 visit_times DESC
```

I expect the output :

```sql
+--------+---------+-------------+
| url_id | user_id | visit_times |
+--------+---------+-------------+
| 265338 |       4 |           1 |
| 265207 |       5 |           2 |
| 265338 |       1 |           2 |
+--------+---------+-------------+
```

Each user only finds the one with the most url_id.

Click Here  [Online Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/044ad/1) . Thanks folks!

Comment: what is your current query's output?

Comment: @Fahmi You can open the link above to see the results, now I have found all the results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On MySQL 8+ a fairly clean solution uses `ROW_NUMBER` with aggregation:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT url_id, user_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) rn
    FROM visit_actions
    GROUP BY url_id, user_id
)

SELECT
    url_id,
    user_id,
    cnt AS visit_times
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

If you had to do this on MySQL 5.7, here is one way:

```
SELECT
    t1.url_id,
    t1.user_id,
    t1.cnt AS visit_times
FROM
(
    SELECT url_id, user_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM visit_actions
    GROUP BY url_id, user_id
) t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT user_id, MAX(cnt) AS max_cnt
    FROM
    (
        SELECT url_id, user_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt
        FROM visit_actions
        GROUP BY url_id, user_id
    ) t
    GROUP BY user_id
) t2
    ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id AND
       t1.cnt = t2.max_cnt;
```

Comment: my version is 5.7

Comment: @Grocker Honestly, if you have complex reporting needs like this, then maybe it is time to upgrade.  MySQL 5.7 won't be supported forever.

Comment: @Grocker I have given you an option which should run even on MySQL 5.7.  You can see how verbose the code becomes without analytic functions.

Comment: This performance will be too bad, I intend to query all the results and use the code to calculate the results.

Comment: Then maybe you're not using the right database, or the right version.  I don't think there is much of a better way to do this on MySQL 5.7.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a MySQL 5.7 solution. Basically you have to find the maximum number of visits per user and then join the count of visits per user to that table to give the user and urls they have visited most. Note in your sample that yields 6 rows for user 1 as they have visited 6 sites twice.

```
SELECT c.url_id, c.user_id, c.visit_times 
FROM (SELECT url_id, user_id, count( * ) AS visit_times 
      FROM visit_actions 
      GROUP BY user_id, url_id) c
JOIN (SELECT user_id, MAX(visit_times) AS max_visits
      FROM (SELECT url_id, user_id, count( * ) AS visit_times 
            FROM visit_actions 
            GROUP BY user_id, url_id ) c
      GROUP BY user_id) m ON m.user_id = c.user_id AND m.max_visits = c.visit_times
```

Output:

```
url_id  user_id     visit_times
265207  0           2
265338  1           2
265391  1           2
265394  1           2
265396  1           2
265410  1           2
265431  1           2
265338  4           1
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/044ad/54)